# Oracle time based analytics

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement to calculate summary statistics aggregated by specific custom time periods. Specifically, a restaurant chain is open 24 hours a day. I need to calculate statistics like total sales by period, where periods are "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner" and "Overnight". For this company, the official day for which they track statistics begins after dinner. So the 24 hour period that consititutes an official day starts at 8PM and runs until 8PM CST) the next day. That is one period. Another period is "Overnight" which runs from 8PM to 5:30AM. I put these definitions into a table called "tdef" like so:

```
drop table tdef cascade constraints 
;

create table tdef 
(
    cd char(3) not null,
    start_ts date not null,
    stop_ts date not null 
)
```

And then I insert the definitions into the tdef table, stored as dates where the start date always begins on Jan 1 1900, and if it spans across midnight, then it ends on Jan 2 1900. Like so,

```
insert into tdef (start_ts, stop_ts, cd) 
values
(
to_date('1900/01/01 20:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
to_date('1900/01/02 19:59:59', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
'24H'
);

insert into tdef (start_ts, stop_ts, cd) 
values
(
to_date('1900/01/01 10:30:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
to_date('1900/01/01 13:29:59', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
'LUN
);

insert into tdef (start_ts, stop_ts, cd) 
values
(
to_date('1900/01/01 15:30:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
to_date('1900/01/02 08:29:59', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
'ON'
);
```

I have a very large table (about 2.5 billion rows) which contains all register transactions. I need to summarize sales by date (their defintion of 8PM-8PM), product and time dimension and store this in a table for fast access reporting. The table should look like this:

```
Dec 12 2011, Hamburger, 24H, 1000
Dec 12 2011, Hamburger, ON, 100
Dec 12 2011, Hamburger, LUN, 400
```

Here is what I did to accomplish this, I added two date columns to the transaction table which are the time of the transaction on 1/1/1900 and 1/2/1900, like so:

```
to_date(concat('01/01/1900 ', tran_tm), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'),
to_date(concat('01/02/1900 ', tran_tm), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
```

I indexed these two columns. Then I created a cross look up table that associated transaction ids with time codes. Each transaction code may be in more than one time defintion. So it looks like this:

```
24H, 1
24H, 2
24H, 3
...
LUN, 100
LUN, 101
LUN, 102
...
ON, 1
ON, 2
...
```

I used two insert select statements to accomplish this:

```
select  t.trans_id, td.cd, to_date(to_char(to_date(concat(to_char(ts, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), to_char(td.stop_ts, 'hh24:mi:ss')), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss', 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyymmdd')
from trans t, tdef td
where ts1 >= td.start_ts and ts1 <= td.stop_ts

select  t.trans_id, td.cd, to_date(to_char(to_date(concat(to_char(ts, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), to_char(td.stop_ts, 'hh24:mi:ss')), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss', 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyymmdd')
from trans t, tdef td
where ts2 >= td.start_ts and ts2 <= td.stop_ts
```

The third field is the "official date". The way that this works, assume a transaction happened at 12/12/2011 8:01PM, then the ts1 field would be 1/1/1900 8:01PM and the ts2 field would be 1/2/1900 8:01PM. In the first query, this field would join to the cd '24H' and 'ON'. And the official date would calcuate as 12/13/2011 for '24H' and 12/13/2011 for 'ON'. This transaction would not join on the second query becuase it is outside the date range. Assume a transaction happened at 12/13/2011 12:05PM. On the first query, ts1 would join like so: '24H' for the date 12/13/2011, 'LUN' for the date 12/13/2011.

Once I have this table, it is easy to aggregate:

```
select tdef_trans.dt, sum(sales) from trans, tdef_trans where trans.id = tdef_trans.id and tdef_trans.cd = 'LUN'
```

Although this solution appears to be working, I am betting there is a more elegant way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: No. Not homework. Real life. I modified the situation some by applying the concept to a restaurant because that is industry I think most people understand. In practice, the data is from online auctions, which I think is a more difficult context to grasp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do data warehousing (it sounds like it), then you may find it easiest to make a table that has every second of the day in it, and which period it belongs to. That will only be 86400 rows.

Then your query becomes a relatively simple join to this time dimension

Comment: Thank you. I like this idea and I used it once before. But it is not immediately clear how to handle the "official day" crossing the midnight barrier using this method? Or time periods that cross the midnight barrier.

Comment: Time periods crossing the barrier are not an issue, since each second states which period it is in. So second 86399 is in "24H", as is second 0. As for your "official" day, I suggest creating a Date dimension with a row for every day since a reasonable epoch out until a reasonable far future (still only 365.25 rows per year). In each row, store (amongst many other things) the start and end timestamp of the "official day", ensuring only one boundary is inclusive. Joining to the date dimension by that column will reveal which "official day" a transaction belongs to.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly, you are suggesting to create a time dimension table from this sql: `select to_date('19900101', 'YYYYMMDD') + numtodsinterval(n, 'day') as "dt", to_date(concat(to_char(to_date('19900101', 'YYYYMMDD') + numtodsinterval(n-1, 'day'), 'YYYYMMDD'), ' 20:00:00'), 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') as "start_ts", to_date(concat(to_char(to_date('19900101', 'YYYYMMDD') + numtodsinterval(n, 'day'), 'YYYYMMDD'), ' 19:59:59'), 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') as "stop_ts" from ( select level n from dual connect by level <= 7305 )`

Comment: Not quite. I'm suggesting two dimension tables. one is the Time Dimension, with 86400 rows in it (one for each second of the day) and a column defining which time period that second falls within. (maybe other useful columns like an AM/PM indicator, too). The second table is the Date Dimension, which has columns defining everything about whole days. Insert rows for as many years as you would like to track, one per day. Have columns that include the "friendly name" of that day, and of particular interest for you the start and end timestamps of the official day. PL/SQL may be easiest to populate

Comment: Within the time dimension table, a time may fall under more than one period. For example, "Breakfast" may overlap with another definition "Morning Rush". In this case, would you create multiple time dimension tables, include multiple rows in one time dimension table or have a code field in the time dimension table and duplicate 0-86400 seconds?

Comment: Is one advantage to using seconds in the time dimension table that a join on a number is faster than a join on a date range (between...and)?

Comment: That becomes a bit of a stylistic choice. I don't think there is a single correct answer to that. You could snowflake out and have a TimePeriods dimension attached to the Time dimension that defines which period(s) any given second belongs to. This could be seen as a factless fact table, also.  The Time dimension uses seconds because it is information only about the time of day, not the full date. To get a full date/time, you need values from both the Date and Time dimensions

Comment: Thinking about this more, I could include the "offical day" specifications in the Time Dimension table by including an offset field in that table. For example, define a time period called '24H'. If the seconds correspond to 8:00PM to 11:59:59, then the offset is 1 and if the seconds correspond to 12:00:00AM to 7:59:59PM then the offset is 0. This way I can determine the "official date" by joining to this table and adding the offset to the transaction date. This offset then would need to be included for all time dimensions. I can post some code for exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an I/O for every record in the transaction table to map the second of the transaction to the business period seems like a steep price to pay.  Perhaps you could instead store and pivot the data, like the query below:

```
select case 
         when txn_ts - trunc(txn_ts) > numtodsinterval(20, 'hour')
           then trunc(txn_ts) + 1 
           else trunc(txn_ts)     
       end as business_day,
       sum (case when (   txn_ts - trunc(txn_ts) > numtodsinterval(20, 'hour')
                       or txn_ts - trunc(txn_ts) < numtodsinterval(5.5, 'hour')
                 then txn_amt else 0 end) as overnight_sales,
       sum (case when (   txn_ts - trunc(txn_ts) >= numtodsinterval(5.5, 'hour')
                      and txn_ts - trunc(txn_ts) <  numtodsinterval(11, 'hour')
                 then txn_amt else 0 end) as breakfast_sales,
       sum (case when (   txn_ts - trunc(txn_ts) >= numtodsinterval(11, 'hour')
                      and txn_ts - trunc(txn_ts) <  numtodsinterval(4, 'hour')
                 then txn_amt else 0 end) as lunch_sales,
       sum (case when (   txn_ts - trunc(txn_ts) >= numtodsinterval(11, 'hour')
                      and txn_ts - trunc(txn_ts) <  numtodsinterval(4, 'hour')
                 then txn_amt else 0 end) as dinner_sales
  from txn_table
 group by case when txn_ts - trunc(txn_ts) > numtodsinterval(20, 'hour')
             then trunc(txn_ts) + 1 
             else trunc(txn_ts)     
          end
```

So for every business day, you've got four values, one for each segment of the business day.  (I put in guesses as to the breakfast/lunch and lunch/dinner breakpoints.)   Building aggregations off of this table should be pretty easy.

See [Creating Histograms with User-Defined Buckets in the Oracle Data Warehousing Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm#i1007516) for other examples, including a non-pivoted version.

Comment: this solution proved very helpful in our redesign. essentially, there is really no need to capture the session offset in a table. this can be handled in procedure logic. end users don't care that it is stored. no reason for it. thanks.